# count wthout invalid use group of function mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-select-db

I have a table like this,

```
CREATE TABLE order_match
    (`order_buyer_id` int, `createdby` int, `createdAt` datetime, `quantity` decimal(10,2))
;

INSERT INTO order_match
    (`order_buyer_id`, `createdby`, `createdAt`, `quantity`)
VALUES
    (19123, 19, '2017-02-02', 5),
    (193241, 19, '2017-02-03', 5),
    (123123, 20, '2017-02-03', 1),
    (32242, 20, '2017-02-04', 4),
    (32434, 20, '2017-02-04', 5),
    (2132131, 12, '2017-02-02', 6)
;
```

[here's the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/712b43/15)
on this table, order_buyer_id is id of the transaction, createdby are the buyer, createdAt are the time of each transaction, quantity are the quantity of transaction

I want to find out the maximum, minimum, median and average for each repeat order (the buyer with transaction > 1)

so on this table, expected results are just like this

```
+-----+-----+---------+--------+
| MAX | MIN | Average | Median |
+-----+-----+---------+--------+
|   3 |   2 |     2.5 |      3 |
+-----+-----+---------+--------+
```

note: im using mysql 5.7

I am using this syntax

```
select -- om.createdby, om.quantity, x1.count_
       MAX(count(om.createdby)) AS max,
       MIN(count(om.createdby)) AS min,
       AVG(count(om.createdby)) AS average
  from (select count(xx.count_) as count_
          from (select count(createdby) as count_ from order_match
                 group by createdby
                 having count(createdby) > 1) xx
        ) x1,
        (select createdby
           from order_match
          group by createdby
          having count(createdby) > 1) yy,
        order_match om
 where yy.createdby = om.createdby
   and om.createdAt <= '2017-02-04'
   and EXISTS (select 1 from order_match om2
                where om.createdby = om2.createdby
                  and om2.createdAt >= '2017-02-02'
                  and om2.createdAt <= '2017-02-04')
```

but it's said

```
Invalid use of group function
```

Comment: Created by #19 made two orders of quantity 5.  Why is your expected max 3 then?

Comment: nope sir, i dont want to look at the quantity of order, but the frequency of order, on this case createdby 19 order  2 times, and 20 order 3 times

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: im using 5.7 sir

Comment: Computing the median using 5.7 is a real pain.

Comment: yes sir, can you just helping me without the median

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try aggregating by `createdby`, and then taking the aggregates you want:

```
SELECT
    MAX(cnt) AS MAX,
    MIN(cnt) AS MIN,
    AVG(cnt) AS Average
FROM
(
    SELECT createdby, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM order_match
    GROUP BY createdby
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
) t
```

To simulate the median in MySQL 5.7 is a lot of work, and ugly.  If you have a long term need for median, consider upgrading to MySQL 8+.

Comment: which part i should add to insert this syntax: where yy.createdby = om.createdby
   and om.createdAt <= '2017-02-04'
   and EXISTS (select 1 from order_match om2
                where om.createdby = om2.createdby
                  and om2.createdAt >= '2017-02-02'
                  and om2.createdAt <= '2017-02-04') because i have several condition about time and date

Comment: I think you should edit your question and clearly define what a repeat order is.

Comment: so basically the data dummy are the data between 2017-02-02 until 2017-02-04, on the real case, it's the data between 2017 until now, so i need the syntax to define the time range that differently (not just in 2017-02-02 until 2017-02-04)

Comment: your syntax nearly right but i need the syntax which display the time range so i can 
change as needed

Comment: thankyou sir, i just solve it with your syntax, have a nice day